# When running cv on a Joomla install, what directory should I use?

Tags: joomla, cv

In the [documentation for adding schedule jobs](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/jobs/#commands) to crontab it says

```
cv api job.execute --user=cronuser --cwd=/var/www/example.org
```

It does not explain which directory the `--cwd` should indicate, the webserver installation root, the Joomla CiviCRM component directory (`.../administrator/components/com_civicrm`) or the CiviCRM root (`.../administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm`).

I've tried all three but get

```
In Factory.php line 137:
                               
  Failed to start application  
                               

vars:show [--out OUT] [--flat [FLAT]] [--level LEVEL] [-t|--test] [-U|--user USER]
```

My problem might be something completely different of course, so I reported the problem [here](https://github.com/civicrm/cv/issues/139).

UPDATE: This was after updating to, or beyond, CiviCRM 5.56, which introduced compatibility with Joomla 4 but introduced an incompatibility with Joomla 3.

Comment: I'd like to comment that I had the same exact error message using version 5.56.0. I gave up on calling the api that way ultimately.  Instead,  first I generated a curl command in the api3 explorer by running `Job.execute`. Then I created an api key for the civicrm user https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/api-keys/ using the MySQL method. Finally, I placed the generated api key and site key in the curl string and copied it into a .sh file. I run that .sh file from my server as a cron job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question is that the directory should be anywhere within the website, so given a webroot of `/var/www/html` any of these should work

```
/var/www/html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm
/var/www/html/administrator/
/var/www/html/
```

The actual problem I had was unrelated and caused by [this bug](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/4060).